# Vue.js v-model to local state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-model

I am passing in data to my component though props. I use `beforeMount` to store the data in the local state via the data function. I then need to update that local state `onchange`.

I am attempting to use v-model to data bind to the local state but when I change the input value it doesn't change the data function.

I think I am missing something simple... Help is appreciated, thanks! :)

**HTML**

```
<div id="labDataWrap" v-if="showLabData">
        <h2>Cannabinoid Profile</h2>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="( value, key ) in cannabanoidProfile" :class="[ key.toLowerCase() ]">
                <md-field class="md-focused">
                    <label> {{ key }} </label>
                    <md-input v-model="cannabanoidObj[key]" type="number" :name="key" :value="value">{{ value }}</md-input>
                </md-field>
            </li>   
        </ul>
        <h2>Terpene Profile</h2>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="( value, key ) in terpeneProfile" :class="[ key.toLowerCase() ]">
                <md-field class="md-focused">
                    <label> {{ key }} </label>
                    <md-input v-model="terpeneObj[key]" type="number" :name="key" :value="value">{{ value }}</md-input>
                </md-field>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="buttonWrap">
            <md-button id="saveLabData" @click="saveLabData">Save</md-button>
            <md-button id="closeLabData" @click="toggleLabData">Close</md-button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
name: "Row",
props: ["other props omitted for post","cannabanoidProfile", "terpeneProfile"],
beforeMount(){
    this.cannabanoidObj = this.cannabanoidProfile;
    this.terpeneObj = this.terpeneProfile;
},
data: function(){
    return {
        cannabanoidObj: {},
            terpeneObj: {},
            isDisabled: true,
            showLabData: false
        }
    },
```

Comment: Did it work if u change md-input to normal input?

Comment: What do mean by "doesn't change the data function"? Because the data function only called once to initialize component. When you type in the input box did the number change or it stuck at your initial value? If the value changed then the binding actually worked. Also you can get rid of the `:value="value"` since the v-model already handle that behind the scene.

Comment: @DatPham what I mean is when I change the input value the local state in the data function doesn't change to reflect the new value.

Comment: @Aldarund I've succesfully v-modeled md-inputs in the rest of the app.

Comment: But still does it work without md-input or no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#ad):

> Due to the limitations of modern JavaScript (and the abandonment of Object.observe), Vue cannot detect property addition or deletion.

To change property in your `cannabanoidObj` use `vm.$set`

Comment: I tried @change="setter(cannabinoidObj, key, value)" to a method of...

setter(obj, key, value){
   this.$set(this.obj, key, value);
}

Didn't work.

Comment: I also tried @change="Vue.set(cannabanoidObj, key, value)" and that didn't work either.

Comment: Also does not work...@change="vm.$set(cannabanoidObj, key, value)"

Comment: @change="$set(cannabanoidObj, key, value)"

Comment: Any idea!? I don't know what to do at this point aside from potentially hiring someone : / ...I don't want to add a watcher to each input because there potentially will be hundredsss!

Comment: I figured the bug out. It happened to be the old value was getting passed through when it needed to be $event.target.value not value. I did it a more manual way using a method function instead of a direct Vue method. From my understanding, despite not implementing it myself, your approach should work.